# Dry orgasm after masturbation but got semen (I am not sure) in pee sometime later does that invalidates my fast?

Tags: sharia, ramadan, masturbation, helping

Assalamo Alaikum
I masturbated while fasting and had no semen ejaculations but after sometime when I went to pee. I am not sure but I think I got semen in my pee but I again will say I am not sure. I have OCD and I  make things up when they are not there but I am not 100% sure I think I saw a white blob while peeing but I didn't felt anything I only felt pee does this invalidate fast and plus I heard that masturbation is makrooh but if I have a exam tommorow and if my fast is broken will Allah punish me tommorow. I made dua a lot and asked for forgiveness. Kindly answer this issue for me. Thanks